# How to find the first character of one dimensional string in java

Tags: java, arrays, string

```
public class solution{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        String[] priya={"priya","nandhni","nithesh","varan","rekha","sri"};
        for(int i=0;i<priya.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(priya.charAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```

This is not working.How can I separate first letters p, n, n, v, r, s to a char array from the above string using java?

Comment: Have you tried some Java code yet?

Comment: Use `String.charAt(index)` to access the character in String

Comment: Post your code. Also specify what output you expect ? A String ("pnnvrs") ? An array ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen am new to java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to directly print the first character of every String without using the  character array, then you can use this snippet:

```
public class solution{
public static void main(String [] args){
    String[] priya={"priya","nandhni","nithesh","varan","rekha","sri"};
    for(int i=0;i<priya.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(priya[i].charAt(0));
    }
}
```

The only thing you are doing wrong is you are not specifying **priya** is an array, after specifying an array & its index value you can only use the string methods on it. So just replace your **priya.charAt(i)** with **priya[i].charAt(0)**.

Hope this solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following snippet:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    String[] priya={"priya","nandhni","nithesh","varan","rekha","sri"};
    char[] firstChars=new char[priya.length];
    for(int i=0;i<priya.length;i++)
    {
        firstChars[i] = priya[i].charAt(0);
    }
}
```

Then you can print or do some manipulating that you want

Comment: tq...but what does this line char[] firstChars=new char[priya.length]; mean?

Comment: That is a temporary array contains your output (array of first characters ).